Recognition of Reform conversions by Open Orthodoxy
Does Open Orthodoxy recognize Reform conversions as valid? If yes, what are the minimal criteria that Reform conversions must to attend to be recognized as valid by Open Orthodoxy?

Don't they follow halacha?

Short answer, no; not if it's performed as a usual Reform conversion. But keep reading.
You need a halachically kosher mikvah, and a panel of three men who keep Shabbos and believe in Torah as the word of God. There's no wiggle room on those. My understanding is that very few, if any, Reform conversions involve those.
(There's an Open Orthodox responsum on what exactly the panel has to witness with their own eyes ... but it's agreed that there must be a panel ascertaining the commitment, immersion, and circumcision-if-male.)
What's more of a gray area is the requirement to accept the yoke of mitzvos. Some have defined that part as "as best the candidate understands it..."
Rabbi Moshe Feinstein was asked about an Orthodox mikvah that receives funding from the broader community, including other denominations. If a non-Orthodox rabbi shows up to perform a conversion there, it's not feasible for the Orthodox rabbis to exclude them. His suggestion is ask for three Orthodox rabbis to witness the conversion, and explain that "hey all sorts of procedures need different specialists." Essentially this would be a conversion where all the mechanics of the ritual itself would be to Orthodox standards, even if the convert's education and planned level of observance would not. (Which he felt was still better than a conversion in which the ritual itself was flawed.)

Where is the open orthodox responsum? (And is Rabbi Feinstein being cited as an authority for what open orthodox views are?)

So there are two issues here. A "glatt kosher" ritual -- kosher mikvah, kosher rabbis -- but with a lesser degree of understanding/commitment on behalf of the candidate -- that's a well-worn subject. Rabbi Jeffrey Fox took it a step further and tweaked the ritual itself. Rabbi Moshe Feinstein was asked in a case where the doorway to the mikvah was very narrow, and only one or two of the three rabbis were able to actually see the dunking itself, he said bediavad that's okay. In the wake of the peeping-Tom-mikvah scandal, Rabbi Fox applied this Igros ...

And said that all three rabbis can just stand outside the mikvah room, hear the woman go okay I'm dunking!  "splash", and declare they have ascertained that an immersion happened. (He then brings in Rabbi Feinstein's famous responsum that the obligation of Chalav Yisrael is not to literally see that the milk is kosher, but to ascertain it.) I've Googled around and it appears that Rabbi Fox's original responsum is no longer at the original links? Not sure where it may be.

I found one that fits your description and edited it in
